# Using LINQ to filter through ID's based on if a certain column is flagged

Tags: c#, linq

I have a database that holds `InvoiceID` and a column boolean flag called `Corrected`. I'm trying to use LINQ to filter whether the database contains these IDs (IDs from another list) but if the `Corrected` flag is set to true, it would not add that ID.

This is simple enough but the issue I am having is that there might be the same object ID more than once in my table and if any of them have the `Corrected` flag I would like to skip them all.

So far my code only skips the ones that have the flag set to true. So for example, I might have 8 records with the same ID but only 4 of them have the `Corrected` flag. Ideally I would skip this ID all together. The below code will only skip 4 and still include the other 4.

```
var uncorrectedIDs = _context.Table1.SelectMany(y => y.Invoices  
                                    .Where(z => invoiceIDsInPeriod.Contains(z.InvoiceId) 
                       && y.Invoices.Any(w => !w.Corrected))));
```

How can I adapt this to the above specification? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GroupBy` could be one approach

```
var notCorrected = 
    _context.Table1
            .SelectMany(table => table.Invoices.Where(i => period.Contains(i.InvoiceId))
            .GroupBy(invoice => invoice.Id)
            .Where(group => group.Any(invoice => invoice.Corrected) == false)
            .SelectMany(group => group)
            .ToList();
```